# Breaking a line without increasing text length

Tags: android, textview

I'm able to break a line using following code:

```
String str1 = "TEST1"; // length = 5
String str2 = "TEST2"; // length = 5

TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.text_view );

textView.setText(str1 + '\n' + str2);
```

But the final text length is equal to 11.

**Question:**

Is there any special character or method that will allow me to reach the same result inside my `TextView` without increasing text length?

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I have a data format, which is stored in JSON. It looks like

```
[{type: line, params: {line params}}, {type: text, params: {text params}, ...]
```

- There is always *line* at the start
- Each paragraph begins with *line* ( so it acts like a line separator which is stored at the beginning of line, not at the end )
- Size of each *line* equals to 1, i.e. each *line* counts as a single character
- Each paragraph ends with *text*'s last character ( not '\n' )
- There are some *line* params ( like BulletList, Numeric list, Paragraph )

I need a strict mapping between my `TextView` and source data, i.e. for each cursor position in my `TextView` I need to count how many characters preceed it in source data.

Comment: If you added some info about what you are trying to achieve we might suggest alternatives. But for this simple question my guess is no.

Comment: @Warpzit I added some information about what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your question my answer will be no. But you could make your own `TextView` and change how it calculates the length of the text by for example ignoring "/n" when counting the length.

Comment: Probably this is what I need, because the answer on my question seems to be "no". I'll try this. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Take two TextViews and add one below another .Then you won't find any length problem.

```
 like :   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView1" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="TextView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As I Said, I'd like to reach the same result inside my `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1 = "TEST1";
String str2 = "TEST2";

TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(str1);
text.append(Html.fromHtml(< br>));
text.append(str2);
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: You don't even have to run your application to see that it doesn't work ( _append_ is a clue ). Also, I do believe that "check & see" is much better than "hope it works". Thanks for the response anyway)

Comment: ok ok ok its working fine for me, n m doing hell with your issues:p

Comment: But the final text length is more than 10, isn't it?

Comment: NO!!! How do u think < br > would add something like '\n' in string ?? Text length wont be changing , its just breaking text in presentation rather than adding a new line in it.

Answer (score -1):

Well there is tricky way

```
    String str1 = "TEST1"; // length = 5
        String str2 = "TEST2"; // length = 5

        textView = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
        textView.setWidth(120);
        textView.setTextSize(20);

        textView.setText(str1  + str2);

//textView.getText().toString().length()  length = 10
```

**in XMl**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work. All I get is "TEST1TEST2" with a big size. Line ain't broken.

Comment: Try reducing textView.setWidth(100);

Comment: Yes, I tried and it worked well. But this is not what I actually wanted, because if you change **TEST1** to **test1** then you will have to change Width again. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: ya this is a work around. if you want to achieve the same result with dynamic text then you need to calculate the width dynamically